# Why RESTful service has to be stateless?

Tags: rest, web-services, stateless

One of the traits of a RESTful service is that it should be stateless i.e. client must provide all the sticky information.

I'm wondering why is that the case?

Comment: Your question is like saying why isn't a cat a dog! Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52858_01/books/OnDemWebSvcs/OnDemWebSvcs_EstablishSessions13.html Scalability is why people go stateless. Server having to maintain session state is an overhead limiting number of concurrent requests.

Comment: I understand stateless is the key for service to become truly scalable. However, RESTful is not invented to address the issue of scalability. Why not stateful REST service?

Comment: Best I can do is point you to the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer - SO is about helping problem solving not debating architectural design standards.

Comment: Citing Fieldings thesis: "REST provides a set of architectural constraints that, when   applied as a whole, emphasizes **scalability of component interactions**, generality of interfaces, independent deployment of components, and intermediary components   to reduce interaction latency, enforce security, and encapsulate legacy systems." While decoupling clients from servers is one of the main goals REST aims at, it also considers scalability and interoperability as integral parts of distributed systems, which REST is just a proposed architecture for.